# Differential amplifier problem

Tags: amplifier, signal, gain, differential

I really can't determine what my professor meant by this. He wanted me to calculate parameters of BJT differential amplifier that will have -100 amplification for signals difference and -1 for their sum. What is confusing me is this -1 for sum of the signals. Is this meant for common mode signal? But common mode is (s1 - signal 1, s2 - signal 2) (s1+s2)/2. Should I took -1/2 for common mode amplification? I'm confused also because BJT amplifiers attenuate common mode signals and I can't take 1, because amplification is typically below 1.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yes, the "sum" of the inputs is 2x the common-mode signal. You seem to be on the right track.

Comment: As far as I can remember, Sedra/Smith microelectronics book has a good description of BJT differential amplifiers with all kinds of design tutorials. Hopefully you will have it or maybe your school's library